# Search The Venue for the Check-In via FourSquare inIOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, foursquare

I have integrated the `Foursquare` for displaying the near by venues. I have used [This GitHUB Code](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2) for this.

Reference API for search venues is [Foursquare Search api](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search)

It works fine for displaying the near by venues in the Table View.

As you seen in api parameter i give `limit parameter = 50`. so,it display 50 nearby venues.
I got the resultant venues in one array.

I also put search the venues above tableview. So,When user will enter something in search bar it finds the result from the array. It also works fine.

**Problem:**  But now I want to find the venue through searchBar text from whole FourSquare Database & not just from the array.

I have already searched a lot for the api which provides this functionality but I could not get any help.

**Is there any API of FourSquare which takes a venues name as the parameter & give the result according to it??**

Thank you,

Comment: You could use the [explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) or [suggestcompletion](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/suggestcompletion) functions.

Comment: @theaob, Great help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foursquare removed searching for venues with search function. Instead you could use [explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) or [suggestcompletion](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/suggestcompletion) functions.

Comment: But i used the same api [Foursquare Search api](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) with the query parameter.

Comment: It seeems that you can use the search api.